# How to set border in af:inputText in Chrome 73.0?

Tags: oracle-adf

I'm having a problem. My customer want one of their website to show in GG chrome instead of IE (they usually use IE before). One of recently problem is that the inputText in GG Chrome have no border, but they have border in IE. So my customer want to make border visible in GG Chrome. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try modifying the input text skin ? https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/documentation/skin-editor-docs-409056.html

Answer (score 1):

you can manipulate style of af:inputText box by adding css code to contentStyle property under style tab in component properties.

```
<af:inputText label="Label 1" id="it1" contentStyle="border: 10px solid black;"/>
```